# In pure JS, how can I get the Json content

Tags: javascript, json

Supposing I have this external json:

```
<script id="data" src="https://website.com/datas.json"></script>
```

Created with this code:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var e = document.createElement("script");
    e.setAttribute("id", "data");
    e.src = "https://website.com/datas.json";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e);
}
```

How can I get this json content to parse it after ?

This is what I tried:

```
var data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('data').innerHTML);
```

Thanks.

Comment: you can't - you can use jsonp or ajax.

Comment: You could grab it using `window.fetch()` (ajax as Daniel A White says)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0):

you can directly load the json in javascript like below:

```
const response = await fetch('https://website.com/datas.json');
const data = await response.json();
```